# Spring Boot @Autowired creating instances on a runtime

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-boot, autowired

As most of Spring Boot new users I have a problem with @Autowired :D

I've readed a big amount of topics about this annotation here But still can't find proper solution for my problem.

Let's suppose that we have this Spring Boot hierarchy:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Class, that we wanna instantiate every time it's called:

```
@Service
public class TestWire {
    public TestWire() {
        System.out.println("INSTANCE CREATED: " + this);
    }
}
```

Out get controller, that creates new SomeRepo object every request:

```
@RestController
public class CreatingRepo {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public void postMessage() {
        SomeRepo repo = new SomeRepo();
    }
}
```

Finally, class, that uses @Autowired to create  TestWire instances:

```
public class SomeRepo {
    @Autowired
    private TestWire testWire;

    public SomeRepo() {
        System.out.println(testWire.toString());
    }
}
```

Let's assume, that we make GET request to "/" several times.

So, as a result, TestWire class will isntantiate only when project builds and neither **@Scope(value = "prototype")**, nor **proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS** wont help.

Any ideas how to create new instances at runtime? I mean, how can we do it in "Spring way"? Without factories and other things, only Spring DI through annotation and configuration.

Upd. A piece of stack trace, where instance created:

```
2015-11-16 20:30:41.032  INFO 17696 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
INSTANCE CREATED: com.example.TestWire@56c698e3
2015-11-16 20:30:41.491  INFO 17696 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@12f41634: startup date [Mon Nov 16 20:30:37 MSK 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-11-16 20:30:41.566  INFO 17696 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/]}" onto public void com.example.CreatingRepo.postMessage()
```

Comment: The problem is that you're using `new SomeRepo()` thus the instance of `SomeRepo` is not managed by Spring. If you want/need to get a new instance of SomeRepo every time `CreatingRepo#postMessage` is executed and by using `new` operator and let Spring manages the instance of the bean (this is, enabling autowiring capabilities and other Spring goods) you could use `@Configurable`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza 
I've changed my controller, now it uses `@Autowire` to inject SomeRepo class, which is annotated with `@Configurable` and `@Service`. 
It seems that I'm using injection of SomeRepo wrong, because it still uses same instance of TestWire. Do you have any example or links?

Comment: You may try doing some research about how `@Configurable` works, like you need to enable aspect weaving.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, thanks for info. Now it's a bit tricky for me, but I think, I'll be back to detailed review soon)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understood you correct you need to annotate the `SomeRepo` like this:

```
@Service
@Scope(value = "prototype")
public class SomeRepo { 
// ...
}
```

**Option A:**

Instead of instantiating the class with `new SomeRepo();` you ask the `BeanFactory.getBean(...)` for it.

```
@RestController
public class CreatingRepo {
    @Autowired
    BeanFactory beanFactory;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public void postMessage() {
        // instead of new SomeBean we get it from the BeanFactory
        SomeRepo repo = beanFactory.getBean(SomeRepo.class);
    }
}
```

**Option B:**

You should also be able to get the Bean like this (over paramters without the `beanFactory`):

```
@RestController
public class CreatingRepo {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public void postMessage(SomeRepo repo) {
        // instead of the BeanFactory and using new SomeRepo you can get it like this.
    }
}
```

Comment: @Supo oddly enough, this contradicts what you were asking: *how can we do it in "Spring way"? Without factories and other things, only Spring DI through annotation and configuration*.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, unfortunatly I have no time right now, to do better research (5 hours to deadline :)), but this forks for me. Under the Factories I mean a little different thing (where every time we call factory method, we calling explicitly `new Bean`) . I didn't know about this type of bean creation (I mean outside the `xml` config). Thanks for your help, anyway, I'm gonna try at home next weekend :D

Comment: I've updated the post to show how to avoid the BeanFactory.